# Write data in an Smart Contract dynamic array

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm trying to understand storage in Solidity.
I'am doing the Node Guadrian quest (if someone know).

So I have a Smart Contract deployed at the adresse 0xb1d01315081351dbb747c3db92754acf8686a219 (https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xb1d01315081351dbb747c3db92754acf8686a219)

```
`// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Temple {
uint128 public entrance;
address public mainHall;
mapping(uint8 => mapping(uint8 => address)) public gardens;
bytes20[] public chambers;

/// Write data to the contract's ith storage slot
function write(uint256 i, bytes32 data) public {
    assembly {
        sstore(i, data)
    }
 }
}`
```

Using hardhat I have to write my address to gardens[20][22].

Here is what i've done:

```
`const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

const temple = await ethers.getContractAt("Temple", "0xb1d01315081351DBb747c3DB92754acF8686A219");
// const Temple = await ethers.getContractFactory("Temple");
// const temple = await Temple.deploy();

console.log("Temple address:", temple.address);

// Set a higher gas limit for writing data to the contract
const gasLimit = 300000; // Adjust this value as needed

// Convert your address to bytes32
// const encodedAddress = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(["address"], [deployer.address]);
const encodedAddress = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(["address"], [deployer.address]);

// Calculate the storage slot for gardens[20][2]
const slotForGardens20 = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(["uint8", "uint8"], [20, 2]));

// Calculate the storage slot for gardens[20][22]
const slotForGardens2022 = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(["uint8", "bytes32"], [22, slotForGardens20]));

// Use the write function to write your address to gardens[20][22]
await temple.write(slotForGardens2022, encodedAddress);
await temple.write(ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(["uint8", "uint8"], [20, 22])), encodedAddress, { gasLimit });


// const addressInSlot = await temple.read(20, 22);
// console.log("Address read from gardens[20][22]:", addressInSlot);

}

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
});`
```

but it did'nt work .

If someone can Help me. Thank you !